# JSHint and angular-mocks error

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, jshint, angular-mock

When i run JSHint over my Jasmine tests using angular-mocks, i get errors for the "module" or "inject" function. How can I fix this? I know i can define those methods as globals in the .jshintrc, but is this the elegant way to solve this?

'module' is not defined
'inject' is not defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see here:
https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/blob/master/.jshintrc
The angular seed project follows that practice. So it seems to be quite accepted.
I suggest you to copy the linked jshintrc.

The file's content if the link would change:

```
{
  "globalstrict": true,
  "globals": {
    "angular": false,
    "describe": false,
    "it": false,
    "expect": false,
    "beforeEach": false,
    "afterEach": false,
    "module": false,
    "inject": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds ok to me. I fix the Jasmine functions with the "jasmine": true option. (http://jshint.com/docs/options/#jasmine) - so it seems I only need to add "module" & "inject"

Comment: For future reference, one can replace `module` with `angular.mock.module` and `inject` with `angular.mock.module` in the code